# How can I return the first set of numbers from PHP string? Regex or Preg_Replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I don't know what to use as doing str_replace and other methods will cause code bloating.

I want to get the first few digits from this string - everything after should be ignored. So get the first set of numbers and after the space or anything else - remove it.

```
$size = $data;

The $data tab is filled with ONE of the following:

$data="18 Bespoke(Size:S Colour:106)"; 
$data="148 Bespoke(Size:M Colour:2334)"; 
$data="Enter Colour Here";
$data="(sometimes it is empty)";
```

It should return

`18` or `148` - the first set of numbers and remove the `Bespoke(Size:M Colour:2334)` includes removing the spaces. Was going to do a `str_replace` but would take forever. It should only return the first numbers, so if `$data="457 Bespoke(Size:MS Colour:3734)"` it should echo out `457`

Comment: Just try this: `/^(\d+)(?:\s+)?/`
This says: Match multiple digits include it in the results, followed by whitespace but not include it in the results. Maybe what you're looking for.

Comment: Most solutions that have been given assume that the number is the first thing on the line (they all start with `^(\d` ). Is that in fact what you need? Or just "the first occurrence of one or more digits"?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I managed to do this. Feel free to welcome better edits or improvements.

```
$data= "3434 any will always choose first numbers not these 223"
$solution= substr($data, 0, strpos($data, ' '));
echo $solution;
```

Output would be

```
3434
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a regex that finds "everything from the first digit up to something that is not a digit". In other words:

```
(\d+)
```

Feed this into `preg_match()` as `preg_match('(\d+)', '18 Bespoke(Size:S Colour:106) ', $matches);` and if true (a sequence of one or more numbers is found), $matches[1] will contain the first number (`18` in this case) in its entirety. If that is not what you are after, please explain more clearly.

Comment: preg_match() returns only true or false, not the number you want.

Comment: Very good @Floris but see my answer on this page, it gives the user exactly what they want in one simple line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one-liner:

```
preg_replace('/(\d+)\s.*/', '$1', $data);
```

To explain what it's doing:
/ and / surround a regex pattern.
( and ) surround a "capturing group" which can be used later.
\d+ matches one or more digits.
\s matches a space.
.* matches everything else to the end.
$1 is a backreference to the first capturing group.

So, the above will match everything in the string and replace it with what it finds in the brackets, which should be just the number.

Answer (score 0):

Is `$data` just one large value with both in it? Or is it separate values. If it's separate values you'd just do:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    preg_match('/^(\d+) B/', $value, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[1)) {
        $values[] = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

`$values` will then contain all the numbers.

Comment: I think you need `+` - "at least one digit". `*` would match "zero digits".

Comment: You are right, but if you require at least one digit then you might not have a match, and it should probably be tested before assigning it to the array.

Comment: No, I do not want an array as they a separate .. updated the question. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

This regex with `m` flag should work:

```
$s = <<< EOF
18 Bespoke(Size:S Colour:106) 
148 Bespoke(Size:M Colour:2334) 
Enter Colour Here
(sometimes it is empty)
EOF;

if (preg_match_all('/^(\d+)/m', $s, $m))
   print_r($m[0]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 18
    [1] => 148
)
```

Comment: I only want it to return 18 or 148 the data value is sometimes one line

Comment: So you just want to return very first number from the input?